# SQL Server backup to URL fails if file exists

Tags: sql-server, azure, database-backups

I am attempting to backup a database to my Azure Blob storage. The databases are relatively large... between 1 and 30 Gig.

I have successfully backed up the first day, but on subsequent days, I get an error stating that the file already exists and that I need to use the WITH FORMAT.

But I need to do a differential backup, as the load of data on a full backup would be very slow and pricey.

I get the error "MyBackup.bak exists on the remote endpoint, and WITH FORMAT was not specified.".

What I am trying to do is:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [MyDatabase]' 
TO URL = 'https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/dbbackups/Container/', MyDatabase.bak', 
WITH CREDENTIAL = 'AzureDBBackupsContainer'
, DIFFERENTIAL
, COMPRESSION;
```

I have seen that a differential backup is supported when using URL backups.

Is this actually not possible, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct in stopping you, because you need to keep the first full backup.
When you restore your database, you will

- Restore from the full backup
- Apply the differential backup

Your script should generate a unique name. I do this by appending the date and time to the backup filename:

```
DECLARE
   @now DATETIME,
   @datePrefix VARCHAR(MAX),
   @timePart VARCHAR(MAX),
   @backupFileName VARCHAR(MAX),
   @fullUrl VARCHAR(MAX),
   @blobServiceEndpoint VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @now = GETDATE();
SET @datePrefix = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112);
SET @timePart = RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(hh, @now)), 2) 
              + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(mi, @now)), 2)
              + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(ss, @now)), 2);
SET @backupFileName = 'MyDatabase_' + @datePrefix + @timePart + '.bak';
SET @blobServiceEndpoint = 'https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/';
SET @fullUrl = @blobServiceEndpoint + 'Container/' + @backupFileName;
BACKUP DATABASE [MyDatabase]' 
    TO URL = @fullUrl
    WITH CREDENTIAL = 'AzureDBBackupsContainer'
    , DIFFERENTIAL
    , COMPRESSION;
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. So I should do an initial full backup first, which I seem to have successfully done, and then DIFFERENTIAL thereafter? We have no reason to go back in time ever. i.e. When we do a restore, we just always want the latest. So to restore, we would need to restore the full, then each subsequent backup? And then maybe once a month, do a full, and remove all the differentials?

Comment: @Craig: That's correct. I've always used transaction log backups instead of differential backups myself. Your differential backups will get bigger each time until you reset by doing a full backup. You'll need to watch it to see at what interval it's worthwhile to perform a full backup.

Comment: Thanks... I'll lookup BACKUP LOG then... But on the surface, is that a case of one initial backup, and then Backup Log thereafter, using the same LOG file name?

Comment: @Craig: Each log backup file must have a unique name, because log backups are incremental. When you restore from Log backups, you must restore from full backup first then apply EACH log backup in order. In contrast to this, with differential backups you restore from full backup and then only apply the most recent differential backup.